# Problema dimensiones y nombres en dataframe

Tags: r

Estoy trabajando con el paquete FD para calcular diversidad funcional
Utilizo los script base que ofrece el paquete a partir de mis dos bases de datos. Una base se llama abundancia y la otra se llama items
abundancia:

```
Mtrisp  Amphi   Mithrac Omalaca Actae   Neopiso
Asp 0   0   0   5   0   0
Afr 0   0   10  15  0   0
Boe 5   0   0   0   5   0
Bpl 0   0   20  0   0   0
Cci 5   0   5   25  0   0
Cer 5   0   0   0   0   0
Cae 15  5   5   5   10  5
Cca 20  0   0   25  15  0
Cle 0   10  10  15  0   10
Dic 0   0   0   20  0   0
```

items:

```
Creci   Long    Calci   Fort    Mol For Uso
Asp R   T   N   D   si  RE  D
Afr L   P   A   M   no  RE  S
Boe R   P   N   M   si  E   S
Bpl R   T   N   M   si  RE  S
Cci R   T   N   D   si  RF  D
Cer R   T   N   D   si  RF  D
Cae R   T   N   D   si  EF  D
Cca R   T   N   D   si  RF  D
Cle R   T   N   D   si  RF  D
Dic R   P   N   M   si  A   S
```

Cuando realizo el siguiente código:

```
ex7 <- dbFD(trait, abund, corr = "lingoes")
print(ex7)

# Para el segundo comando (calculando FGR)
ex7 <- dbFD(trait, abund, calc.FGR = TRUE)
print(ex7)
```

Obtengo los siguientes errores:

```
ERROR:
Different number of species in 'x' and 'a'.

Species labels in 'x' and 'a' need to be identical and ordered
alphabetically (or simply in the same order).
```

Las especies son:
Asp, Afr, Boe, Bpl, Cci, Cer, Cae, Cca, Cle, Dic
El numero diferente de especie lo he intentado solucionar mediante la transposición de filas `t(abund)` y columas para que tengan el mismo numero de especie en x y en a. Lo cual asumo que es a cantidad de fila de trait con la cantidad de columna de abund, en este caso 10 que corresponde al número de especie.
Necesito ayuda  para poder arreglar estos errores. Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos temas, el primero, efectivamente, tienes que "transponer" `abund`, resuelto esto, el problema es que `trait` requiere que las variables sean numéricas, en el caso tuyo, parecieran ser categorías que deberías transformar en factores, y si corresponde, del tipo `ordered` ya que de esta forma es posible calcular distancias.

Esto, obviando los mensajes de la función, funciona:

```
abundancia <- read.table(text="Mtrisp  Amphi   Mithrac Omalaca Actae   Neopiso
Asp 0   0   0   5   0   0
Afr 0   0   10  15  0   0
Boe 5   0   0   0   5   0
Bpl 0   0   20  0   0   0
Cci 5   0   5   25  0   0
Cer 5   0   0   0   0   0
Cae 15  5   5   5   10  5
Cca 20  0   0   25  15  0
Cle 0   10  10  15  0   10
Dic 0   0   0   20  0   0", header=TRUE)

items <- read.table(text="reci   Long    Calci   Fort    Mol For Uso
Asp R   T   N   D   si  RE  D
Afr L   P   A   M   no  RE  S
Boe R   P   N   M   si  E   S
Bpl R   T   N   M   si  RE  S
Cci R   T   N   D   si  RF  D
Cer R   T   N   D   si  RF  D
Cae R   T   N   D   si  EF  D
Cca R   T   N   D   si  RF  D
Cle R   T   N   D   si  RF  D
Dic R   P   N   M   si  A   S", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor=TRUE)

ex7 <- dbFD(items, t(abundancia), corr = "lingoes")
```

De vuelta, cada categoría deberías convertirla en un factor "ordered" cuando corresponda, por ejemplo, imagino que `Long` seguramente lo es.